# Attrib for search-autocomplete

Tags: html, web-scraping, xpath

I want to get a attrib (:suggested-items) from a search-autocomplete tag. I am trying: `.xpath("//search-autocomplete/@:suggested-items")` but it's not working

```
<div data-id="search-autocomplete-vue-app">
   <search-autocomplete :is-search-widget-placeholder="false" :suggested-items="[{&quot;specialization.id&quot;:36,&quot;specialization.name&quot;:&quot;Ginecologista&quot;},{&quot;specialization.id&quot;:78,&quot;specialization.name&quot;:&quot;Psiquiatra&quot;},{&quot;specialization.id&quot;:76,&quot;specialization.name&quot;:&quot;Psic\u00f3logo&quot;},{&quot;specialization.id&quot;:67,&quot;specialization.name&quot;:&quot;Ortopedista - Traumatologista&quot;}]" :top-search="false" :widget="false" search-location="" search-query="" </search-autocomplete>
</div>
```

Comment: Your `search-autocomplete` isn't closed properly. Also, is that what the scraper will see or is it going to be rendered into some other html tags?

Comment: this is going to be what the scrapper will see.